# Nested Tag inside URL tag in Django Template

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a list of items in my template which produce a table of hrefs. Now I want to send back the item.name to the appropirate view function based on the clicked item. The code should look something like this:

```
{% for item in myList %}
    <li><a href="{% url myView arg="{{ item.name }}"%}"> {{ item.name }} </a> <li>
{% endfor %}
```

And the problem is the created nested tag and the `{{ item.name }}` inside the view arg which doesn't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

`{% url myView item.name %}` should work, if the url pattern expects a *positional argument*! See the documentation of the [url template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#url)!